# Git repository organization for a game development

Tags: git, repository, project-management

We need to develop a game in team and of course the best way is to do it with a git repository. We wonder about how structure it as best for a game development project. In particular a game was made by codes and assets (images, sounds, etc), now those assets need to be developed, for example we should store not just the final image (i.e. PNG) but also the project file for that image (Photoshop, Illustrator...) and this for all assets. 
Now we can mind some different solutions, for example keep everything in the same repository (divided by folders) [Bad idea, I suppose], split in two repository: one for assets project and the other for the code + asset final, or create a single repository for every asset project.. So there are many many solutions, but what is the best accuracy? Of course the final decision is always directed from team needs, but what are the best/common practices to make a repository for a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is whatever works best for you.
Maybe take a look at [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), but in my opinion, keeping assets and code in one repository is also fine. 
Especially when you think about adding some new cool code which also includes a new graphic, you would have to commit the same feature two times. This can lead to some troubles due to the fact that this could lead to inconsistency and a lot of additional management overhead.

Therefore, I would use one repository with a neat folder structure. Take a look at [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/), maybe there are already some nice gitignore files for the type of project you create.

Good Luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can place all the assets, resources in one repository. It doesn't matter what the file type is, Git will make sure you have the updated version every time you update. Creating more than one repositories lead to issues in keeping each of them up-to-date.